# Sprites and Bullets not moving C++

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm currently making a top-down 2D game and am trying to render bullets and sprites to the screen. For testing purposes I have set a new bullet and sprite to render when the arrow keys are pressed and both should move diagonally upwards.

This is where I invoke new sprites and bullets by adding them to a vector;

```
if(inputState->isKeyPressed(VK_UP))
{
    enemys.push_back(Enemy(playerX, playerY, 100));
}
if(inputState->isKeyPressed(VK_DOWN))
{
    bullets.push_back(Bullet(playerX, playerY, 100));
}
```

I then update their possitions in the update methos;

```
for each(Enemy e in enemys)
    {
        float x = e.getEnemyX();
        float y = e.getEnemyY();
        x += PLAYER_MOVEMENT_SPEED * deltaT;
        y += PLAYER_MOVEMENT_SPEED * deltaT;
        e.setEnemyCoord(x,y);
    }

for each(Bullet b in bullets)
{
    float x = b.getX();
    float y = b.getY();
    x += PLAYER_MOVEMENT_SPEED * deltaT;
    y += PLAYER_MOVEMENT_SPEED * deltaT;
    b.setCoord(x,y);
}
```

I then render all objects in the vectors;

```
for each(Enemy e in enemys)
{
    float x = e.getEnemyX();
    float y = e.getEnemyY();
    renderEnemy(x,y);
}

for each(Bullet b in bullets)
{
    float x = b.getX();
    float y = b.getY();
    renderBullet(x,y);
}
```

The sprites and bullets appear on screen but don't move and I don't know why.

Comment: Are you periodically executing update? I mean if you call update 1 time you should not expect any movement.

Comment: They are just in the update function.

Comment: `*new Bullet(playerX, playerY, 100)` is horrible, it should just be `Bullet(playerX, playerY, 100)` since it's being passed by value, you're leaking the newly allocated memory. Aargh.

Comment: @unwind and it leaks...

Comment: what is deltaT ? Remember 0 * x = 0

Comment: deltaT is the time between each frame

Comment: You've created the Matrix, thanks for destroying humanity.

Answer (score 2):

You are using the scary `for each` Microsoft extension. I think you must also use a ["tracking reference"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8903062a.aspx) to be able to modify the objects in the collection. I think you're just modifying the looping variable now.

Comment: Got it working. It was the stupid for each thing I was using. Normal for loop syntax worked fine!

Comment: Or, instead of using Microsoft extensions, you can you a good new-fashioned C++11 `for (Enemy& e : enemys)`.